# Error "expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int"" in a for loop

Tags: c++

The following code will not execute, as I get an error:

> expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int"

```
int n, m, v[100];
cin >> n >> m;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        cin >> v[i];            
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){ 
        int nr = v[i][j];
    }
}
```

It's saying that the `j` in `int nr = v[i][j]` must have pointer-to-object, why does this happen?

Comment: `v` is declared as a single dimension array, but you use it in the second loop as a two dimensional array.

Comment: `v[i]` is already a number, you can't take anything by index `[j]` from just a number

Comment: Ok, yes, that's my bad. Thanks for pointing that out!! @gthanop

Comment: No problem. I am not sure why I answered in comments (where instead comments should be used to request clarifications on the question AFAIK), so I am sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a 2 dimensional array, you must specify it first. You better [take a look](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Emrmiller/15-110/Handouts/arrays2D.pdf).
Back to the code. If you understand the logic, this code will work for you.

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;
int v[100][100];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            cin >> v[i][j];            
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){ 
            cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

This code returns the retrieved data back to you. That way, you can fully understand its accuracy. Have a nice day